# Generate a large number of the same byte

Tags: shell-script

I'm generating a binary file as test data for a piece of software. The test data should consist of a long array of the same byte. If it was a zero byte I would use /dev/zero. Is there a command to transform the zeros from there into another byte, or a command to do a similar thing?

I came up with this bash script, but this solution doesn't feel ideal. It can only generate a fixed number of bytes. There is surely a way to do this with a simpler script.

```
for i in $(seq 5); do
    echo $'\x10'
done
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `/dev/zero` to generate `n` characters of your choice:

```
head -c "$n" /dev/zero | sed 's/\x00/a/g'
```

where you should replace the `a` with whatever the character was that you wanted.

For example:

```
$ n=50; head -c "$n" /dev/zero | sed 's/\x00/a/g'
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

This assumes that you have a `sed`, such as GNU `sed`, that is capable of understanding `\x00`.

Alternatively, `tr` could be used:

```
$ n=50; head -c "$n" /dev/zero | tr '\00' 'a'
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: This is much more sensible than the answers in the duplicate question.

Comment: @jacwah - in fact, no. `sed` is a terrible direction to take this - though they are presented as such, `tr` and `sed` in this capacity are by no means equal. the nearest they could come is w/ `sed y/\\x00/a/`, but then you still have to work w/ `sed`'s `\n`ewline buffer. `tr` should be preferred in every case - `sed` should never have entered into this at all. `head -c` doesn't make a lot of sense here, either. Just do: `printf %050s | tr \  a`. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/188658/52934) which that other, in my opinion, should have been made a duplicate of in the first place.