# Writing an unlimited number of defined values into a file

Tags: shell, files

I can use `/dev/zero` or `/dev/urandom` to write values into a file. Is there also a way to write an unlimited amount (just restricted by a command line switch maybe) of defined numbers (e.g. `1`, `2`, etc.) into a file?

I know about `echo "1" > file` but I need moooore!

The file should contain the same string value repeated without newlines. Ideally I could write bit test patterns like `0xAA` or `0x55`, but I guess I can manage that myself once I know how to write one value.

Comment: Possibly related: [Writing a character N times using the printf command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188658/writing-a-character-n-times-using-the-printf-command)

Comment: `seq 1 100000000000`

Comment: @123: thanks, that helped my do exactly what I need

Comment: What do you want the file to contain? Repetitions of the same byte? Repetitions of the same line? Repetitions of the same byte sequence that doesn't end in a newline? A sequence of consecutive integers? Something else?

Answer (score 4):

For an unlimited amount of arbitrary data, don't forget about `yes`!

```
$ yes 42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
42
^C
```

Hit Control-C when you've had enough!

Alternatively to Control-C, use `timeout`:

```
timeout 10 yes 42
```

Answer (score 1):

While loop

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html

plus basic math

```
 $ a=1
 $ a=$(($a+1))
 $ echo $a
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining

- `seq` mentioned by @[123](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117145/123) in a comment and a [few `seq` examples](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/seq/)
- the help of ["echo without newline" (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193466/echo-without-newline-in-a-shell-script)
- knowing that I need `busybox`

I found the following works best for my needs:

```
for i in $(busybox seq 10); do echo -n "1" >> filename; done
```

where `10` defines the number of items to write.