# Copy or Repeat Columns as Columns

Tags: bash, awk

I could pipe the output below to `awk '{print $1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1}'` to get the desired output as posted in the [print alphabet wave at CodeGolf SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89283/17282).

Is there a better way to copy/repeat columns as another column (*vertically*?) using bash and/or other *nix utilities?

```
for i in {0..25}; do 
  printf \\$( printf '%03o' $((i+65)) );
  printf \\$( printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65)) ); 
  echo; 
done

AB
BC
CD
DE
EF
FG
GH
HI
IJ
JK
KL
LM
MN
NO
OP
PQ
QR
RS
ST
TU
UV
VW
WX
XY
YZ
ZA
```

Comment: how about `paste -d "" <(echo {A..Z} | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo {B..Z} A | tr ' ' '\n') | perl -pe 's/.*/$&x13/e'`

Comment: ... or just `... | perl -lne 'print $_ x 13'` maybe?

Comment: @spasic `{B..Z}` -- didn't even think of it, brilliant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could simplify your 2 printfs + 1 echo to a single printf I think:

```
for i in {0..25}; do 
  printf '%b%b\n' \\$( printf '%03o' $((i+65)) ) \\$( printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65)) )
done
```

If you want to keep everything in the shell, you could use the trick described here [Writing a character N times using the printf command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188658/writing-a-character-n-times-using-the-printf-command), i.e.

```
for i in {0..25}; do 
  printf "$(printf '%b%b' \\$( printf '%03o' $((i+65)) ) \\$( printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65)) ))%.0s" {1..13}
  printf \\n
done
```

or, more transparently

```
for i in {0..25}; do 
  printf -v xy '%b%b' \\$( printf '%03o' $((i+65)) ) \\$( printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65)) )
  printf "${xy}%.0s" {1..13}
  printf \\n
done
```

---

If you're not set on using pure shell, then a couple of other techniques to reduplicate each letter pair that come to mind are

1. using perl's multiplication operator

   ```
   . . . | perl -lne 'print $_ x 13'
   ```
2. using a sed loop

   ```
   . . . | sed -E ':a; /.{26}/! s/../&&/; ta'
   ```

---

In fact, you could do the letter pairing in sed as well

```
$ printf \%b {A..Z} A \\n | 
    sed -E '/^Z/! s/(.)(.)/&\n\2/; P;D; b' | sed -E ':a; /.{26,}/! s/../&&/; ta'
ABABABABABABABABABABABABAB
BCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBCBC
CDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCDCD
DEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDEDE
EFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEFEF
FGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFGFG
GHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGHGH
HIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHIHI
IJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJIJ
JKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJKJK
KLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKLKL
LMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLMLM
MNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMNMN
NONONONONONONONONONONONONO
OPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOPOP
PQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQPQ
QRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQRQR
RSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRSRS
STSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTSTST
TUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTUTU
UVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUVUV
VWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVWVW
WXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWXWX
XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY
YZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZYZ
ZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZAZA
```

---

*It should be possible in a single sed invocation, something like*

```
printf \%b {A..Z} A \\n | 
  sed -E ':1; /^Z/! s/(.)(.)/&\n\2/; :2; /.{26}\n/! s/../&&/; t2; P;D; b1'
```

*but I can't quite get the terminating condition right without resorting to exotic GNU extensions*

```
printf \%b {A..Z} A \\n |  
  sed -E ":1; /^Z/! s/(.)(.)/&\n\2/; :2; /.{26}(\n|\')/M! s/../&&/; t2; P;D; b1"
```

Comment: the printf+sed solution is missing the row of `ZA`s... perl one-liner: `perl -e 'foreach $i (0..25) {$s=chr(65+$i).chr(65+($i+1)%26) ; print "$s"x13,"\n"}'`

Comment: @spasic thanks - I missed that it was supposed to wrap around, should be fixed now. I didn't even attempt a perl solution, given that [a 26 byte one](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89291/15701) (!) was already posted

Comment: all sorts of crazy solutions there..

Answer (score 1):

Without attempting to optimise your code in any way (that's the challenge!), you could do

```
x=$(printf ..statement1..)
y=$(printf ..statement2..)
```

and then simply

```
echo "$x$y$x$y$x$y$x$y$x$y...."
```

eg

```
for i in {0..25}; do 
  x=$(printf \\$( printf '%03o' $((i+65)) ))
  y=$(printf \\$( printf '%03o' $((-~i%26+65)) )) 
  echo "$x$y$x$y$x$y$x$y"
done
```

There are a *lot* of ways to optimise this, though.

Comment: What are some areas for improvement? Not looking for answers, but some hints would be great ... Please (_:

Comment: One example: Instead of `y=` the second printf line could be `x=$x$(printf...)` and now the final echo would just be `echo "$x$x$x$x"` because `$x` would hold both characters; the echo line is now a lot shorter.  Could you make the `printf` itself simpler?